# Java subclasses constructors with expanding parameters

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to expand the constructors parameters for each subclass of the superclass. 
For example:

```
public class Car{
protected String regNum;
protected Car(String regNum){
    this.regNum = regNum;
  }
}
public class GasCar extends Car{
protected double gasEmissions;
protected GasCar(double gE){
    gasEmissions = gE;
  }
}
```

Is there a way where I could use the parameters in the Car constructor in the GasCar constructor by inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: not directly, but kind of. What you maybe are looking for is a call to a super-constructor, e.g.:

```
public class Car {

    protected String regNum;

    protected Car(String regNum) {
        this.regNum = regNum;
    }
}

public class GasCar extends Car {

    protected double gasEmissions;

    protected GasCar(String regNum, double gE) {
        super(regNum);
        gasEmissions = gE;
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind, that calling a super-constructor (or any other constructor) is the first thing you need to do in a constructor.

EDIT: As the other 2 answers said, you need to call a super-constructor anyway (if you don't call it directly, it will try to call the one without parameters).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try compiling this code? It won't compile, because the GasCar constructor isn't calling a super constructor.

Also, you are using the word inheritance in the wrong way. Parameters are not inherited - methods are. And constructors are never inherited, because it doesn't make sense - When you subclass an object, it needs its own constructor(s)

Comment: Could you elaborate? I would really love to learn if there is something I've not understood with inheritance :)